# Elasticsearch search for number as a string

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an object - `Organization` with a property `int Number` that I would like to search for as a string, e.g. 
search string **12**
would return Organizations with `Number = 12`, or `Number = 5123` etc...
Now, if I set `searchStr = "123"` there are results where 123 is contained in all fields, but searching for non-numeric characters, e.g. "goo" fails with `System.Exception: Invalid elasticSearch response`

This is the Organization object:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And the code that creates the index:

```
var indexState = new IndexState();
var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
indexSettings.Analysis = new Analysis();
indexSettings.Analysis.Analyzers = new Analyzers();

var customAnalyzer = GetStandardAsciifoldingAnalyzer();

indexSettings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(STANDARD_ASCIIFOLDING_ANALYZER_NAME, customAnalyzer);

indexState.Settings = indexSettings;

var response = await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(indexName, index => index
    .InitializeUsing(indexState).Map<Organization>(
        x => x.Properties(ps => ps
            .Number(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Id)
                .Type(NumberType.Integer)
            )
            .SearchAsYouType(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Name)
                .Analyzer(STANDARD_ASCIIFOLDING_ANALYZER_NAME)
            )
            .Text(s => s
                .Name(n => n.SecondName)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Text(tt => tt
                        .Name("ngram")
                        .Analyzer("ngram_analyzer")
                    )
                )
            )
            .Text(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Number.ToString())
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Text(tt => tt
                        .Name("ngram")
                        .Analyzer("ngram_analyzer")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here is the search "query":

```
string searchStr=  "123";
ISearchResponse<Organization> searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Organization>(s => s
                                    .Index(indexName)
                                    .Query(q => q
                                        .Bool(b => b
                                            .Must(c => c
                                                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                                                    .Query(searchStr)
                                                    .Type(TextQueryType.BoolPrefix)
                                                    .Fields(f => f
                                                           .Field(p => p.Name, 3)
                                                           .Field("name._2gram", 3)
                                                           .Field("name._3gram", 3)
                                                           .Field(p => p.SecondName, 2)
                                                           .Field("secondName._2gram", 2)
                                                           .Field("secondName._3gram", 2)
                                                        .Field(p => p.Number, 1)
                                                    .Field("number._2gram", 1)
                                                    .Field("number._3gram", 1)
                                                    )
                                                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                                                )
                                            )
                                            )
                                    )
                                    .Size(limit)
                                    );
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Searching for non-numeric characters in a numeric field _should_ raise an exception.

Comment: I want to search in string and numeric fields as in string. I don't get why it should raise exception when the query contains all fields...